# Xcode 4.2 Soundboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2

I'm trying to create a Soundboard app, but I'm having difficulty finding a way to play sounds and making the sound stop when the other sound button is pressed. I want to prevent the sound from overlapping each other. And each sound will loop. Is there a way to prevent more than one sound playing at the same time? I have not found a way in any tutorials. The code I'm using for the soundboard looks a little like this:

```
-(IBAction)sound1 {
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound1", CFSTR      ("wav"), NULL);

UInt32 soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

-(IBAction)sound2 {
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound2", CFSTR      ("wav"), NULL);

UInt32 soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Comment: [This answer might help you.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9244552/927947)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop a sound Before PLaying another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244087/stop-a-sound-before-playing-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) so you can play or stop the sound at any time, and use delegate methods to determine if the sound was interrupted or has finished.

Comment: +1 And `AVAudioPlayer` is rich in ARC'y goodness so it won't leak memory like a sieve; As the code above does.