# Stopping sound in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, audio

***Hi all,
Please look at the code below, i want to be able to stop the sound when the same button is clicked, another button is clicked and even when going back to the home screen. Not sure what to do here,***

**FoxViewController.m**

```
#import "FoxViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer_Fox;

@interface FoxViewController ()

@end

@implementation FoxViewController

-(IBAction) Fox;
{
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"new"ofType: @"mp3"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: fileURL error: nil];
[newPlayer play];



}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString*)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
 {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

**FoxViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer;

@interface FoxViewController : UIViewController

-(IBAction)Fox;

@end
```

***Your help is much appreciated, Justin.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain one `flag` say `BOOL soundPlay` as global variable in `FoxViewController.h` file

Now in `FoxViewController.m's viewDidLoad` method

```
 soundPlay = TRUE;
```

Action button will be like this:

```
-(IBAction) Fox;
{
 if(soundPlay){
   soundPlay = FALSE; //made false for next time another condition will be used.
   NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"new"ofType: @"mp3"];
   NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
 newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: fileURL error: nil];
  [newPlayer play];
 }
 else
 {
    if([newPlayer isPlaying])
    {
       [newPlayer stop];
    }  
 }
}
```

For `stopping sound` in `background` add this method if not added

```
 -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
 {
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

   //stop background sound
   if([newPlayer isPlaying])
   {
    [newPlayer stop];
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing, the sentence to STOP the sound file is:

```
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID (soundFileObject);
```

Explanation (Important to understand):

I have a table view with 18 different sound files. When user select a row must sound the corresponding file and when select another row, it must STOP the previous sound and play other.

All this stuff it is necessary:

1) Add to your project "AudioToolbox.framework" inside "Build Phases", inside "Link Binary With Libraries"

2) In header file (in my project it calls "GenericTableView.h") add these sentences:

```
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
SystemSoundID soundFileObject;

@property (readwrite) CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
@property (readonly) SystemSoundID soundFileObject;
```

3) In implement file (in my project it calls "GenericTableView.m") add these sentences:

```
@synthesize soundFileURLRef;
@synthesize soundFileObject;
```

And inside your "Action" implementation or in my case, in:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// That is the question: a way to STOP sound file
//
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Very important to STOP the sound file
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID (soundFileObject);

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------


// In my project "rowText" is a field that save the name of the 
// corresponding sound (depending on row selected)
// It can be a string, @"Alarm Clock Bell" in example

// Create the URL for the source audio file.
// URLForResource:withExtension: method is new in iOS 4.0.
NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:rowText withExtension:@"caf"];

// Store the URL as a CFURLRef instance
self.soundFileURLRef = (CFURLRef) [soundURL retain];

// Create a system sound object representing the sound file.
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURLRef,&soundFileObject);

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundFileObject);

[soundURL release];
}
```

4) Finally, in the same implement file (in my project it calls "GenericTableView.m"):

```
- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];

AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID (soundFileObject);
//CFRelease (soundFileURLRef);
}
```

I must to comment "CFRelease (soundFileURLRef)" because the App ends unexpectedly when user leaves the table view.

All this code is proportioned by Apple. In this link you can find even a sample code to test directly in your iPhone simulator.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SysSound/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008018-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2